# Bar-Line chart in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm trying to put together a bar chart and a multiple line plot grouped by a column chart into a single bar-line chat in SAS Enterprise Guide.

If I select a bar-line chart, the only option is to assign columns to - 
bar sum of and (bar chart)
line sum of task roles. (line chart)

However, I do not need any aggregations and I only have to print the graph for the data set as is.

Please let me know the best way to generate a bar line chart in SAS Enterprise Guide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what your dataset looks like, the `sum` might well be the answer.  If your dataset only has one row per bar or line you're looking for, then asking for the sum will get you the sum of one item - i.e., its value.

For example, let's say you take the built-in dataset `sashelp.class`.  You want a bar-line chart with the heights and weights of the students as the bars and lines, respectively.

You select "Column to chart" -> "Name", then drag Height over to "Bar sum of", and drag Weight over to "Line sum of".  Then you get a nice bar/line graph showing heights and weights - technically sums, but sum of one number is itself.

If your dataset doesn't have a variable appropriate for `Column to chart` (i.e., an identifier variable that would represent a single row in the data), you may need to modify your data to conform to this; otherwise SAS doesn't have a good way to tell what is supposed to be in one bar.

[image: Bar-Line Graph Options]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time!